# What is the use of `--assemble` in `kur data --assemble mnist.yml`?

Tags: python, deep-learning

when would we choose to run `kur data --assemble mnist.yml`, I walked through the code on related to `--assemble`, each step makes sense, but I don't get the whole picture for the purpose of it.

could you explain why you design this function and when should we use it?

Thanks

---

**Feedback to @ajsyp answer below**

You mentioned:

> But there are parts of the training pipeline that may need/create OTHER data sources, NOT just the ones in the train.data(mutatis mutandis) section. For example, the CTC loss function, which is widely used as a soft-alignment loss function in sequence learning (e.g., speech recognition), needs to know the length of each ground-truth transcript. Now nothing in the data sections mention anything about transcript lengths, or even input audio source lengths.

If so, then Kur should start to get the additional sources like transcript length after [line 156](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/__main__.py#L156). See transcript length inside a single sample of a batch as a result of `kur data --assemble -n 1 speech.yml`:

```
Entry 1/16:
  audio_source: /Users/Natsume/kur/lsdc-train/audio/67290d16-4254-4db3-93cf-a9c26cc6e19b
  duration: 1.445
  transcript: [26  6 20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
  transcript_length: [3]
  transcript_raw: [26, 6, 20]
  utterance: [[ 1.05875487  0.77517924  0.15939959 ...,  0.44732655  0.52782439
  -0.44943174]
 [-0.37000188  1.01170798  0.53420591 ...,  0.73733297  0.42373239
  -1.09549656]
 [ 0.637711    0.91922504  0.68830267 ...,  0.55688627 -0.62501853
   0.52738557]
 ...,
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]]
  utterance_length: [143]
  utterance_raw: [[ 1.05875487  0.77517924  0.15939959 ...,  0.44732655  0.52782439
  -0.44943174]
 [-0.37000188  1.01170798  0.53420591 ...,  0.73733297  0.42373239
  -1.09549656]
 [ 0.637711    0.91922504  0.68830267 ...,  0.55688627 -0.62501853
   0.52738557]
 ...,
 [ 0.96143945  0.76925231  0.58252107 ...,  0.39418582  0.46883116
   0.05069899]
 [ 0.54131455  0.61457148  0.45849029 ..., -2.30826005  0.54976478
   0.87326668]
 [-0.57543387  0.94335625  0.510369   ...,  1.44453525 -1.6265138
   0.45963185]]
```

However, when I ran the line L151 of `prepare_data` and inside `spec.get_provider` at [line 255](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/kurfile.py#L255):

```
providers = spec.get_provider( # L151 of prepare_data
        args.target,
        accept_many=args.target == 'test'
    )

suppliers[k] = [        # L255 of get_provider
                Supplier.from_specification(entry, kurfile=self)
                for entry in v
            ]
```

I did get all 8 data sources including transcript length, without running the codes after L156: see the transcript length source below

```
(Pdb) pprint(suppliers['default'][0].__dict__['sources'])
{'audio_source': <kur.sources.vanilla.VanillaSource object at 0x10ad0a3c8>,
 'duration': <kur.sources.vanilla.VanillaSource object at 0x10ad0a320>,
 'transcript': <kur.supplier.speechrec.Transcript object at 0x10ad0ab38>,
 'transcript_length': <kur.supplier.speechrec.TranscriptLength object at 0x10ad0a0f0>,
 'transcript_raw': <kur.supplier.speechrec.RawTranscript object at 0x100ab14e0>,
 'utterance': <kur.supplier.speechrec.Utterance object at 0x10ad0a2b0>,
 'utterance_length': <kur.supplier.speechrec.UtteranceLength object at 0x10ad0a160>,
 'utterance_raw': <kur.supplier.speechrec.RawUtterance object at 0x10a933898>}
```

Does it indicate that `transcript_length` is not an additional source? If so, What are the additional sources sought by kur after line L156 of `prepare_data`?

Once Kur identified the additional source, kur will store the additional sources into `BatchProvider` for acessing, right? then which function exactly get the additional sources into a same BatchProvider at [Line174](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/__main__.py#L174)?

---

More findings:

- `kur data speech.yml` and `kur data --assemble speech.yml` print out the same output, there is no additional output because of `--assemble`
- when I ran `spec.get_provider` at [line 255](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/kurfile.py#L255), I got `SpeechRecognitionSupplier` object with 8 data sources, 3 of them extracted into `data`. `transcript_length` source is not extracted. However, after `merge_suppliers` at [L268](https://github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/kurfile.py#L268), it seems all 8 data sources are extracted into the newly created `BatchProvider` instance. This is why without `--assemble`, I still got all 8 data sources printed out.
- in the case of `kur data mnist.yml`, unlike that of `speech.yml` case, the supplier object has no additional `sources`, just 2 data sources; when the provider object is initialized, there is 2 data sources in total; whereas, `speech.yml` case its supplier object has 8 data sources in total and only extracted 3 into data, after provider initialization, its provider has 8 data sources prepared to give in each batch, without using `--assemble`. It seems the additional data sources are there from the start.

`kur data --assemble speech.yml` print out 8 data sources below:

- kur.supplier.speechrec.RawUtterance object at 0x1160d2198>,
  kur.supplier.speechrec.UtteranceLength object at 0x1160670b8>,
  kur.supplier.speechrec.Utterance object at 0x116067198>,
  kur.supplier.speechrec.RawTranscript object at 0x10c8e3c18>,
  kur.supplier.speechrec.TranscriptLength object at 0x10c09b208>,
  kur.sources.vanilla.VanillaSource object at 0x116067048>,
  kur.supplier.speechrec.Transcript object at 0x10bf6e4e0>,
  kur.sources.vanilla.VanillaSource object at 0x116067128>

`--assemble` did introduced a seemingly new data source using `target.compile(assemble_only=True)`, but this new data source didn't get printed out, nor it is found inside a `BatchProvider`['sources']:

```
(Pdb) pprint(target.model.__dict__['additional_sources'])
{'ctc_scaled_utterance_length': <kur.loss.ctc.ScaledSource object at 0x117479f60>}
```

So, up to this point, it seems `--assemble` can bring in new data source, but this new data source seems not to be stored in a `BatchProvider` instance, nor can printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @ajsyp from [kur](https://github.com/deepgram/kur)

If you do NOT use `--assemble`, then you will only print out the data sources that were specified (perhaps indirectly) in the Kurfile's train.data (or validate.data, etc.) section.

But there are parts of the training pipeline that may need/create OTHER data sources, NOT just the ones in the train.data(mutatis mutandis) section. For example, the CTC loss function, which is widely used as a soft-alignment loss function in sequence learning (e.g., speech recognition), needs to know the length of each ground-truth transcript. Now nothing in the data sections mention anything about transcript lengths, or even input audio source lengths. So where do they come from?

Kur creates these "auxiliary" data source when the CTC loss function is constructed. If you specify --assemble, then Kur will go a step further than merely looking at your data blocks. Instead, it will try to do as much as possible (short of actually compiling/using the model) to figure out what other auxiliary data sources might be present.

So whether or not you use --assemble depends on what part of the data pipeline you are trying to debug.

---

Further explanation from @ajsyp

> `--assemble`. Right now, Kur **does** , in fact, create these additional data sources, but *only if* `--asemble` if specified. The data source just aren't being added to the provider, which is why you aren't seeing them when you do `kur data --assemble`. I plan on adding that in at some point so you actually can see what gets added. Haven't gotten around to it yet.